# LastPasswordChanged AD B2C Rest API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I am troubleshooting a password expiry issue in azure ad b2c . many people have suggested to check users "LastPasswordChangedTimestamp" . but for this to work i need to be in global administrator role and use

```
connect-msolservice
```

this is not feasible. Can I user any available REST API's and use it with a service principle which has sufficiant rights?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve **`LastPasswordChangedTimestamp`** of all Azure AD B2C users, you can make use of Microsoft Graph API [**Beta version**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and sign in as a user.

***I tried in my environment and got response by running query like below:***

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime
```

**Response**:

[image]

Make sure to assign the permissions like **`User.Read.All`** , **`Directory.Read.All`** and grant admin consent before running the query.

Please **note** that, to retrieve the sensitive information of users like password, you must need **Admin** role or **Permissions consented by Admin**.